# Identify vintage automotive connectors

Tags: identification, connector, vintage

These connectors are from a Ford/Philco electronics unit circa early 1970s. White and blue are male and green is female. Pin pitch is 0.2".

Any ideas for part numbers of modern equivalents that are compatible with these along with the male/female pins? Or alternatively the series/family name of the original connectors?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are all "pin-and-socket" plugs.

Thank you for specifying the pitch, though it is probably 5.03, 5.08, or 5.13 mm.

The single-row ones may be among these:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/standard_093) - Standard .093 Pin and Socket 5.03 (1r) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/0pnq53c3)
- TE - [Commercial .093 Pin and Socket 5.03 (1r)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY&DocType=CS&DocLang=English&DocFilename=ENG_CS_82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY_0508.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/bfmn42qd)
- TE - [Commercial MATE-N-LOK 5.08](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY&DocType=CS&DocLang=English&DocFilename=ENG_CS_82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY_0508.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/fbmfbmdw)
- TE - [Commercial MATE-N-LOK 5.08 L](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY&DocType=CS&DocLang=English&DocFilename=ENG_CS_82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY_0508.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/rpw234q0)

The 2-row one is certainly this one:

TE Commercial MATE-N-LOK

[image: TE 1-480697-0]

{Digikey}

https://www.digikey.com/short/bqdbqpz0

Comment: Many thanks! I've looked through them but those don't use the same polarization as mine - which is a rectangular protrusion on one end. The crimp terminals look right however.